# How to pass variable in command module in ansible

Tags: ansible

i am using folloing task in YAMl file.

`- name: Run deployment of RWI Artifact
  command: "{{ deploy_script }} /home/scripts/lite /application/ a-CL '--Home=/opt/AppServer --appClassLoaderMode=abc'"`

but typically , i am getting following error

> We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
>   missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
>   start a value. For instance:
>
> with_items:
>        - {{ foo }}
>
> Should be written as:
>
> with_items:
>         - "{{ foo }}"

i tried all combination but dont know how to put those quotes correctly.

please suggest

Comment: Add full error message, with `offending line` statement.

Answer (score 1):

In YAML if you start string with quote, it is considered as quoted string, so you must end the string with the same quote.

Try:

```
- name: Run deployment of RWI Artifact
  command: "{{ deploy_script }} /home/scripts/lite /application/ a-CL '--Home=/opt/AppServer --appClassLoaderMode=abc'"
```

I assume that `deploy_script` has no spaces.

Comment: yes. i modified the command and ran again . but same error .. yes deploy_script does not have spaces

Comment: you should not modify original post to test answers... are you sure the problem is with this task?

Comment: ok.. my apologies. yes the issues is with this tsk only. i double checked